# Laravel: Eloquent relationship from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

Still practicing in Laravel. At this time, I have the a page controller that finds all the sections available to the corresponding page (simple HTML sections) and includes them in the blade like this:

```
@foreach(@sections as @section)
  @include('sections.' . $section->filename)
```

Then I have a `sections` table with data for the corresponding section, as well as `columns` column with a JSON data inside, that looks like this:

```
 {"header":"Section column 1", "text":"bruh?", "image_id":""},
 {"header":"Section column 2", "text":"bruh?", "image_id":""},
 {"header":"Section column 3", "text":"bruh?", "image_id":"7"}
```

As you can see, there is `image_id` that should call for filename from the `images` table using Eloquent relationship (I assume it's gonna be One to Many).

Yes, I know that storing JSON inside the table is not the best solution (especially if you want to cross-request data from it), but it is the best I came up with.

So, the question(s) is: **how can I get the filename of the image using just ID from a JSON object** or **is there any different solution, except JSON**?

P.S. `columns` table and JSON format is used for defining some properties, since some of my sections have 3-9 text columns (`col-md-3`), and each of them has a different header, text and image, so I store them inside JSON.

*P.P.S. My JSON format is valid, I just removed some formatting in order to keep this question clear.*

Comment: Fetch JSON data. Convert into array using json_decode(). Pluck 'image_id' from it and make it on query.

Comment: My suggestion is to move this 'sections' JSON data into another table. The result will be a better-organized code, a much clear solution and better performance(a lot better).

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev Isn't additional queries is slower then json_decode? And I am bit stuck with logic - for one section I've got 3-9 columns, and each column may have it's own image, plus - each section may have it's image as well.

Comment: @ArtemUshakov in case you use json_decode for every object you will have to run a query for each section to get the image and will have n+1 problem but if you have an additional table you can get all data in one query. That was my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for JSON relationships.

I've created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

```
class Section extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'columns' => 'json',
    ];

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'columns->image_id');
    }
}

class Image extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function sections()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Section::class, 'columns->image_id');
    }
}

{{ $section->image->filename }}
```

Comment: I have been trying to work out how to access a JSON object, but your documentation does not say much on cases where the JSON object is an array-like below:




"[{\"supplier\":\"228\",\"name\":\"The Making of Harry Potter - Studio Tour London\",\"booking_id\":\"1\",\"koedia\":\"7890\",\"client\":\"2\",\"net\":\"92\",\"sales\":\"95\"}]"

Comment: @JamieRoss Do you mean https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations#array-of-objects?

Comment: yes I do. because I have used your code and used belongToJson. I see you currently don't support this and it is an enhancement on your github repo.
I tried using 'coloumnName->koedia' and 'coloumnName->[]->koedia' but none of them work. It looks as if the json query is not being built in the correct order.

Comment: I struggled whole day to use such nice package. But I am getting the following error: require php ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.2; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.5) does not satisfy that requirement.